# Is there any way to tell apart multiple multi-line outputs from a script?

Tags: bash, perl, unix, sed, pipeline

I am running a script input.sh which has multiple multi-line outputs like so:

```
echo -e 'first \n second'
echo -e 'first \n second'
echo -e 'first \n second'
```

I don't have control over this file, and all I can know is that it will have multiple multi-line outputs.

I need to be able to conduct operations on each individual output from that file in real time as it outputs messages. Buffering is one issue, but not the one I'm asking about here.

I'm simplifying a little, but my problem boils down to this: I want to insert a kangaroo at the end of each individual output. See my attempts below:

```
./input.sh | sed 's/$/kangaroo/'
```

This version above inserts a kangaroo after every newline, not each multiline output.

```
./input.sh | perl -0777 -pe 's/$/kangaroo/'
```

This perl version only inserts a kangaroo after all outputs have finished (one kangaroo total, instead of one kangaroo per output.)

I have tried other variants but it's always one or the other-- a kangaroo after every new line, or a single kangaroo after everything. I tried using `tr` to replace new lines with form feeds, but that didn't make any difference.

How can this be done?

By the way, I've read through [this question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/26284/how-can-i-use-sed-to-replace-a-multi-line-string) and its answers carefully, but they are discussing operating on a file. I was unable to apply the principles described there to a pipeline and reading from stdin.

Comment: Do you have control over the execution of the script? In other words, do you have control over the script that executes `input.sh`? Can you modify the script during its execution?

Comment: Yes, but in truth I'm operating on many scripts with unpredictable content. Input.sh is a stand-in representing a number of bash, python, or ruby scripts.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do to this output? Instead of abstracting the problem and asking for a very narrow ideal, why not post your actual input and desired output?

Comment: I'm trying to tell apart individual outputs from a script, it's as simple as that. I want to do a number of things with them which are completely unrelated to the question. I don't see how telling you what transformations I wish to apply to these multiline outputs would help at all seeing as it is independent of the problem described above.

Comment: The first thing that comes to mind when I think of what you might want to do is this: measure the response time of the commands within a script. Is that your higher-level goal?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's no way to distinguish

```
echo -e 'first\nsecond'
echo -e 'first\nsecond'
echo -e 'first\nsecond'
```

from

```
echo -e 'first\nsecond\nfirst'
echo -e 'second\nfirst\nsecond'
```

Both output the following stream of bytes (represented as hex):

```
66 69 72 73 74 0A 73 65 63 6F 6E 64 0A 66 69 72 73 74 0A 73 65 63 6F 6E 64 0A 66 69 72 73 74 0A 73 65 63 6F 6E 64 0A
```

The stream doesn't contain any information about what these bytes mean or how they were assembled. At best, there could be timing differences.

Answer (score 3):

No; in the general case, there is no way to reliably tell whether two bytes were output separately and buffered together, or output together.

Comment: I mean it makes sense but I so desperately want to believe it isn't true. There's really no way to operate over individual multi-line sequences through a pipeline? This seems like such a useful thing. there are countless uses for being able to put paragraphs through a pipeline rather than just individual lines...

Comment: Maybe you could inject a pipe after each external command which adds `kangaroo` if the last output it has seen was not `kangaroo` in an eternal loop. Not reliable but possibly reasonably accurate.

Comment: Terribly sorry, but I don't really understand what you mean. Could you clarify that suggestion? As is, it sounds like every other line would be kangaroo.

Comment: Like `tail -f` only when you draw a blank from the file handle, print `kangaroo`, then poll again and wait until you receive new input.

Comment: I'm trying to imagine how I would "detect a blank" though-- isn't that the crux of my original question? If two echo statements are executed consecutively, wouldn't there be no "blank" between them ?

Comment: When  `read()` returns zero bytes it means you have exhausted the buffer. Look at the source of `tail`.

Answer (score 2):

You need a trick.

You can try to overrule the `echo` command with your own wrapper !

```
echo() {
   printf "%skangeroo\n" "$(/bin/echo $@)"
}

echo -e 'first \n second'
echo -e 'first \n second'
echo -e 'first \n second'
echo "=================="
echo -e 'first \n second \n first'
echo -e 'second \n first \n second'
```

result:

```
first
 secondkangeroo
first
 secondkangeroo
first
 secondkangeroo
==================kangeroo
first
 second
 firstkangeroo
second
 first
 secondkangeroo
```

Comment: The problem is that not all output is coming from `echo`....I'm running scripts that run other processes, so the output is only sometimes from echo, and oftentimes is the output of a binary.

Comment: In that case the remark of @tripleee (look for chunks of output) might help. Perhaps it is easier to change your requirements: Is there any other way you can find what you want? Look for all multi-line outputs and see what is in the last line (`sed 's/.*second.*/&kangeroo/'`), do you always have 2 lines of output or can you write a wrapper around the binaries too (`mv my_prog my_prog.org` and call `my_prog.org $@` in the script my_prog, that will also add a kangeroo when finished)?